# Breeze doesn't expand TPH entities correctly

Tags: entity-framework-5, odata, breeze

Breeze doesn't expand TPH entities correctly.
When using expand in breeze if you are using TPH expand will only work for the first entity, the others properties will be null. If I change the entity not to use inheritances it works fine. I've also tested returning each entity separately in an expand query that also worked fine.

//client side code

```
        var getResidentById = function (id, obs) {

            var query = EntityQuery.from('Residents')
                .where('id', '==', id)
                .expand('user, currentUnit, leases, leases.unit, leases.leaseStatus');

            return manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                if (obs) {
                    obs(data.results[0])
                }
            }, queryFailed);
        };
```

//Controler Endpoint

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Resident> 
{
   return _context.Context.UserDetails.OfType<Resident>();
}
```

//Model

```
public class UserDetail : EntityBase<int>, IArchivable, IHasPhoto, IDeactivatableEntity, IUpdatable
    {
        public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
        public int LastUpdatedById { get; set; }
        public UserProfile LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUri { get; set; }
        public bool IsInactive { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class UserBelongsToApartmentComplex : UserDetail, IBelongsToApartmentComplex
    {

        public int ApartmentComplexId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApartmentComplex ApartmentComplex { get; set; }

        public virtual bool IsInSameComplexAs(IRelatedToApartmentComplex otherEntity)
        {
            return ApartmentComplexId == otherEntity.ApartmentComplexId;
        }
    }

    public class Staff : UserBelongsToApartmentComplex
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Admin : UserDetail
    {
        public string AccessLevel { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resident : UserBelongsToApartmentComplex
    {
        public string Pets { get; set; }
        public bool HasInsurance { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Lease> Leases { get; set; }
        public int? CurrentUnitId { get; set; }
        public virtual Unit CurrentUnit { get; set; }

        public Resident()
        {
            Leases = new List<Lease>();
        }
    }
```

//response data from sever from endpoint public IQueryable Residents()

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.Resident, RadiusBlue.Core","Pets":"Sadie, a westie","HasInsurance":false,"Leases":[{"$id":"2","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.Lease, RadiusBlue.Core","Start":"2012-05-23T00:00:00.000","End":"2013-05-23T00:00:00.000","UnitId":2,"Unit":{"$id":"3","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.Unit, RadiusBlue.Core","Building":"B","Floor":2,"ModelName":"Tera","RentAmount":2500.00,"NumberOfBeds":1,"NumberOfBaths":3,"UnitName":"102A","IsInactive":true,"Inhabitants":[],"ApartmentComplexId":1,"ApartmentComplex":{"$id":"4","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.ApartmentComplex, RadiusBlue.Core","Name":"The Stratford","StreetAddress":"100 S Park Ave","City":"Winter Park","StateId":10,"ZipCode":"32792","PropertyManagementCompanyId":1,"IsInactive":false,"TimeZoneId":"Eastern Standard Time","TimeZone":{"$id":"5","$type":"System.TimeZoneInfo, mscorlib","Id":"Eastern Standard Time","DisplayName":"(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)","StandardName":"Eastern Standard Time","DaylightName":"Eastern Daylight Time","BaseUtcOffset":"-PT5H","AdjustmentRules":[{"$id":"6","$type":"System.TimeZoneInfo+AdjustmentRule, mscorlib","DateStart":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","DateEnd":"2006-12-31T00:00:00.000","DaylightDelta":"PT1H","DaylightTransitionStart":{"$id":"7","$type":"System.TimeZoneInfo+TransitionTime, mscorlib","TimeOfDay":"0001-01-01T02:00:00.000","Month":4,"Week":1,"Day":1,"DayOfWeek":"Sunday","IsFixedDateRule":false},"DaylightTransitionEnd":{"$id":"8","$type":"System.TimeZoneInfo+TransitionTime, mscorlib","TimeOfDay":"0001-01-01T02:00:00.000","Month":10,"Week":5,"Day":1,"DayOfWeek":"Sunday","IsFixedDateRule":false}},{"$id":"9","$type":"System.TimeZoneInfo+AdjustmentRule, mscorlib","DateStart":"2007-01-01T00:00:00.000","DateEnd":"9999-12-31T00:00:00.000","DaylightDelta":"PT1H","DaylightTransitionStart":{"$id":"10","$type":"System.TimeZoneInfo+TransitionTime, mscorlib","TimeOfDay":"0001-01-01T02:00:00.000","Month":3,"Week":2,"Day":1,"DayOfWeek":"Sunday","IsFixedDateRule":false},"DaylightTransitionEnd":{"$id":"11","$type":"System.TimeZoneInfo+TransitionTime, mscorlib","TimeOfDay":"0001-01-01T02:00:00.000","Month":11,"Week":1,"Day":1,"DayOfWeek":"Sunday","IsFixedDateRule":false}}],"SupportsDaylightSavingTime":true},"Users":[{"$ref":"1"}],"Groups":[],"IsArchived":false,"ApartmentComplexId":1,"Id":1},"Id":2},"ResidentId":3,"Resident":{"$ref":"1"},"LeaseStatusId":4,"LeaseStatus":{"$id":"12","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.LeaseStatus, RadiusBlue.Core","Description":"Lost","Id":4},"Id":1},{"$id":"13","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.Lease, RadiusBlue.Core","Start":"2013-05-24T00:00:00.000","End":"2014-05-24T00:00:00.000","UnitId":1,"Unit":{"$id":"14","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.Unit, RadiusBlue.Core","Building":"A","Floor":2,"ModelName":"Aqua","RentAmount":2000.00,"NumberOfBeds":2,"NumberOfBaths":1,"UnitName":"101A","IsInactive":true,"Inhabitants":[{"$ref":"1"}],"ApartmentComplexId":1,"ApartmentComplex":{"$ref":"4"},"Id":1},"ResidentId":3,"Resident":{"$ref":"1"},"LeaseStatusId":1,"LeaseStatus":{"$id":"15","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.LeaseStatus, RadiusBlue.Core","Description":"Active","Id":1},"Id":2}],"CurrentUnitId":1,"CurrentUnit":{"$ref":"14"},"ApartmentComplexId":1,"ApartmentComplex":{"$ref":"4"},"Id":3,"User":{"$id":"16","$type":"RadiusBlue.Core.Models.UserProfile, RadiusBlue.Core","UserName":"vjiawon@gmail.com","FirstName":"Vishal","LastName":"Jiawon","Age":27,"PhoneNumber":"123 456 7890","IsInactive":false,"UserDetail":{"$ref":"1"},"GroupMembers":[],"MaintenanceRequests":[],"Id":3},"IsArchived":false,"LastUpdatedById":1,"LastUpdatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00","IsInactive":false,"CreatedById":1,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"}]
```

Comment: As inheritance support was only recently added to Breeze, I suspect that this is either a bug, or the Breeze team did not focus on getting TPH to work correctly. Why not voice your concern on Breeze Uservoice at [https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions)

Comment: Put a break point on this line in breeze.debug.js: "throw new Error("Breeze is unable to create an EntityKey for an abstract EntityType: " + entityType.name);" and reload the page.

Comment: never hits that line of code, not sure where it throwing it but somewhere in this method function processMeta(node, mappingContext, meta, assignFn) in firefox it gave the assignFn is not a function error message chrome just says undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not doubt that there is a bug in BreezeJS somewhere.

I can report that, at least as of v.1.3.4, **Breeze can expand multiple navigation properties of a TPH class ... and not just on the first entity returned**.

I just modified the "*can navigate to AccountType eagerly loaded with expand*" test in *inheritanceTests.js* in DocCode so that (a) it also expands the `Status` navigation and (b) the tests are performed on the 3rd entity returned rather than the 1st.

The query is something like this:

```
var em = newEm(); // clean, empty EntityManager
return EntityQuery.from('bankRootTPHs').take(3)
    .expand('AccountType, Status'))
    .using(em).execute().then(success).fail(handleFail);

...
function success(data) {
    var entity = data.results[data.results.length-1]; // get the last one (the 3rd)
    var type = data.query.entityType.shortName;

    if (!entity) {
        ok(false, "a query failed to return a single " + type);

    }
    // more tests
    // I just set a breakpoint and inspected 
    // entity.accountType() and entity.status()
    // Both returned the expected related entities

}
```

I see that both the related `AccountType` and the related `Status` are available from the entity.

So something else is wrong.

### Questions about your Example

First I am compelled to observe that you have a lot of expands. I count 5 related entities. That can hurt performance. I know we're not talking about that but I'm calling it out.

Second, the super class `UserDetail` is concrete but the intermediate derived class `UserBelongsToApartmentComplex` is abstract. You have inheritance class hierarchies that go **concrete/abstract/concrete**. The queried type, `Residents` is one such class. And a class at every level maps to the "UserDetail" table, yes?

I'm pretty sure we didn't test for that scenario ... which is pretty uncommon. I wasn't even sure that worked! For now I have to take your word for it that EF allows such a construct.

It would seem that BreezeJS is confused about it. We'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That worked. Question we made a one to one mapping with the asp.net generated user profile table and our user detail table using the method described here http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx, I was unable to get it to work when doing this. I know EF doesn't really support 1 to 1 do you have any recommendation for trying to use TPH with 1 to 1 mapping with breeze?